# Based Relay Quantum Communication

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

One of the methods to perform Quantum Communication in a long distance is to do it using quantum relays which is known by the relay based long-distance quantum communication. I'm looking for the record of the used relays until now because it seems that i failed knowing it. I've seen some articles about two, three, four relays but i'm not sure what is the record for the quantum relays that have been used for long-distance quantum communication.